# value of li not being displayed with onclick event using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-lists

I am trying to load a list when the users gives types in the input tag like below,

```
$("#search_name").keyup(function(e) {
//After validating the input, I am loading data like below..this works fine..
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "get",
    data: { name : name_value },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
    var height_div=25*(data.split("</li>").length-1);
    $("#myDiv").empty();
    $("#myDiv").append(data);
    $("#myDiv").height(height_div);
    $("#myDiv").show();
    $("#myDiv ul li").hover(
    function() {
        $("#ul_names li").css('backgroundColor','white');
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','#ccc'); },
        function() {
            $("#ul_names li").css('backgroundColor','white');
            $(this).css('backgroundColor','#ccc'); });
    $("#myDiv ul li").click(function() {
        alert($(this).text()); });
    }
});
```

The hover event works, but the click event is not working.

my html

```
<div id="view_others" style="display:none">
    <input id="search_name" type="text" value="Type The Name to Open Specific Individual Artifact's" size="80" style="position:absolute;top:35px;text-transform:capitalize"/>
    <div id="myDiv" style="position:relative;top:50px;left:1px;background-color:white;width:504px;display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

the PHP file returns something like..

```
<ul id="ul_names">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

I tried replacing the click function with

```
    $("#myDiv ul").on('click','li',function() .....
```

but that too didn't work..

can anyone tell me what is it that am doing wrong here ??

Comment: did you checked your click event is working?

Comment: can you create a fiddle link?

Comment: yes the click event is working..what am trying to do is create something like google instant by loading <ul li> data into the div..

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myDiv ul li").hover(function() {
        $("#ul_names li").css('backgroundColor','white');
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','#ccc'); 
}).on('click',function() {
    alert($(this).text()); });
});
```